# How I give action to my custom FBSDK login button in iOS swift

Tags: ios, swift, fbsdk

```
@IBAction func facebookLoginbuttonPressed(_ sender: FBSDKLoginButton) {

    let facebookLogin = FBSDKLoginManager()

    facebookLogin.logInWithReadPermissions(["email"],     fromViewController: self) { (facebookResult:     FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult!, facebookError: NSError!) -> Void in
        print("Facebook login failed. Error \(facebookError)")
    } as! FBSDKLoginManager

}
```

> I am getting error like "Cannot convert value of type '(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult!, NSError!) -> Void' to expected argument type 'FBSDKLoginManagerRequestTokenHandler!'". Please help me to solve this?

Comment: func application(application: UIApplication,
  openURL url: NSURL, options: [String: AnyObject]) -> Bool {
    return GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handleURL(url,
        sourceApplication: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsSourceApplicationKey] as? String,
        annotation: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsAnnotationKey])
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@IBAction func selectFacebookLogin(sender: UIButton)
    {
        let fbLoginManager : FBSDKLoginManager = FBSDKLoginManager()

        fbLoginManager.logInWithReadPermissions(["public_profile", "email", "user_friends"], fromViewController: self)
        {
            (result, error) -> Void in
            if (error == nil)
            {
                let fbloginresult : FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult = result
                if result.isCancelled
                {
                    return
                }

                if(fbloginresult.grantedPermissions.contains("email"))
                {
                    self.getFBUserData()
                }
            }
        }
    }

 func getFBUserData()
    {
        showIndicator()

        if((FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken()) != nil)
        {
            FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me",
                                parameters: ["fields": "id, name, first_name, last_name, picture.type(large), email , gender"]).startWithCompletionHandler(
                                { (connection, result, error) -> Void in

                                    self.hideIndicator()

                if (error == nil)
                {
                   print(result)

                }
            })
        }
    }
```